# check if string only contains "-" and nothing else

Tags: javascript

How can I check if a string only contains `-` in it? No letters or numbers.

I.e. the string is `-` and not `- hi` or `"-1h"`.

Best Regards

Comment: `str === '-'`...!?

Comment: Are you looking for more than one `-`, or just equal to `-`?

Comment: I am looking for a string only containing "-" and maybe a space also, nothing else.

Comment: So, what is it? Exclusively only one "-"? Or "maybe also spaces"? Or maybe possibly something else too?

Comment: @user1665355 You should [edit] your question to clearly explain what you want. The requirements described in your comment are different from the requirements described in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's only the character "-", testing for string equality works:

```
var dashOnly = "-";
if(dashOnly === "-") // use strict comparison operator
    console.log("true");
```

If the dash is surrounded by whitespace, try trimming it:

```
var withSpaces = "  -  ";
if(withSpaces.trim() === "-")
    console.log("true");
```

For multiple dashes, use a regular expression (see also [Grissom's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34419377/4991915)):

```
var reg = /^[-]+$/;        // dashes only
var regSpace = /^[\s-]+$/; // dashes and space characters

reg.test("-");     // true
reg.test("-----"); // true
reg.test("--_");   // false
reg.test("-- --"); // false

regSpace.test("-- --"); // true
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this regex `var reg = new RegExp(/^[-]+$/)`

```
str = "---"
reg.test(str) // true


str = "2---"
reg.test(str) //false

str = "-"
reg.test(str) // true
```

Comment: and what if str = "-" ? will it work?

Comment: It will work, you can try...

Comment: @user How does "----" fulfil your requirement of *"string is `-`"*?!

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex to look for not space or "-", /[^ -]/

var s = " .... ";

s.match(/[^ -]/)===null